# ldap3 bind syntax error in flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, compiler-errors

I am trying to  validate username  and password of users in a flask app using **ldap3**. Normal **ldap**  is not installing in **python 3.5**.

The user is entering username and password through login form, I am trying to  authenticate user with **username / password** and allow them to access the index page if it is authenticated.

Does the authentication return true of false so that I can redirect to next page based on outcome.
The `LDAP_PROVIDER_URL = "ldaps://appauth.corp.domain.com:636";`

Please help me with the code for this.
When I type `appauth.corp.domain.com` or `corp.domain.com`  as HOST  I get  the  following error

> (r_web) C:\Users\dasa17\r_web\RosterWeb\RosterWeb>python Roster.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Roster.py", line 10, in
>   
>       s = Server(appauth.corp.domain.com, port=636, get_info=ALL) NameError: name 'appauth' is not defined
>
> (r_web) C:\Users\dasa17\r_web\RosterWeb\RosterWeb>python Roster.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Roster.py", line 10, in
>   
>       s = Server(corp.domain.com, port=636, get_info=ALL) NameError: name 'corp' is not defined

I made   some modifications  , now   I  am able to run it  by  giving dummy   username and password.  However, I   am getting a different error now.>>> c = Connection(s,user='dasa17',password='',check_names=True, lazy=False,raise_exceptions=False)

> > > c.open()
> > >            Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >            File "", line 1, in 
> > >             c.open()
> > >            File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 57, in   open
> > >               self.connection.refresh_server_info()
> > >             File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 1017,    in refresh_server_info
> > >              self.server.get_info_from_server(self)
> > >            File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\server.py", line 382, in     get_info_from_server
> > >              self._get_dsa_info(connection)
> > >             File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\server.py", line 308, in     _get_dsa_info
> > >                get_operational_attributes=True)
> > >              File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 571,    in search
> > >               response = self.post_send_search(self.send('searchRequest', request,    controls))
> > >             File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 140, in   post_send_search
> > >              responses, result = self.get_response(message_id)
> > >             File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py", line 298, in  get_response
> > >               responses = self._get_response(message_id)
> > >              File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 158, in   _get_response
> > >             responses = self.receiving()
> > >             File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 92, in  receiving
> > >               raise communication_exception_factory(LDAPSocketReceiveError, exc)   (self.connection.last_error)
> > >              ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketReceiveError: error receiving data: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: The initial error you were getting because the hostnames were not quoted. Can you post the line that is currently setting the value of s, now that you have changed that?

Comment: @KevinSchellenberg   Now I rectified the   syntax, not sure why  it is taking any username  and password   and  authenticating.    I    was   inputting username  and password from login.html and if the  username   and password are invalid it will show invalid credentials..

Comment: s = Server('appauth.corp.domain.com',use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(s,'uid=dasa17,dc=corp,dc=domain,dc=com', '', auto_bind=True)

Comment: print(conn)
ldaps://appauth.corp.domain.com:636 - ssl - user: uid=dasa17,dc=corp,dc=domain,dc=com - bound - open - <local: 10.x.3x.x:61128 - remote: 10.x.x.x:636> - tls not started - listening - SyncStrategy

Comment: >>> conn.open()
>>> conn.bind()
True

Comment: Sounds like maybe you are having a different issue now.  I would pass username and password from the login view to your Connection call and if conn.bind() returns True then the credentials are correct and you can log the user in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I   got this   sorted out . Perhaps   because  I had set  raise_exceptions=True,   Setting it to  False  resolved the issue